# C++ operator new overloading, compilation error

Tags: c++, c++11, operator-overloading, new-operator

When I overload new operator globally to track mem leaks, I get compilation error in the following place

```
 ::new(__tmp) _Rb_tree_node<_Val>;
```

looks like they allocate and fill the node there.
Following is the error:

```
/home/symbol/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/include/functional: In static member function 'static void std::_Function_base::_Base_manager<_Functor>::_M_clone(std::_Any_data&, const std::_Any_data&, std::true_type)':/home/symbol/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/include/functional:1870:9: error: '__dest' does not name a type
new (__dest._M_access()) _Functor(__source._M_access<_Functor>());
```

Below is my overloading code:

```
void* operator new(std::size_t sz,char const* file, int line){  
return newImpl(sz,file,line);
}

void* operator new [](std::size_t sz,char const* file, int line){  
return newImpl(sz,file,line);
}

void operator delete(void* ptr) noexcept{
auto ind=std::distance(myAlloc.begin(),std::find(myAlloc.begin(),myAlloc.end(),ptr)    );
myAlloc[ind]= nullptr;
free(ptr);
}

#define new new(__FILE__, __LINE__)
```

Comment: The macro definition does not look right. Generate preprocessor output to see what that macro expands to in the code, it is probably not what you expect.

Comment: why do you need overload if you're using a macro anyway? you can just replace `new` with any function call

Answer (score 2):

```
#define new new(__FILE__, __LINE__)
```

that is illegal.  Under the standard, the behavior of a program with a keyword `#define`d to something else is unspecified.  Your program is ill-formed, no diangostic required.

If you are wondering why you are breaking this particular time, it is because the C++ standard library uses placement new itself where it passes a void pointer to be constructed into.

Your code takes the naked `new` that starts a placement new expression, and replaces it with a different placement new exprssion.  Which then makes the rest of the code nonsense, as we get:

```
new("some file", 1234) (some void pointer) some_type( constructor_args... )
```

which is utterly illegal syntax.

If you want to catch 99% of allocations, retool your code to use a different allocator when creating `std` containers. Sweep your code to replace non-placement `new` with something you can legally `#define` to something different (like `TRACED_NEW` and `TRACED_NEW_PLACEMENT` for placement new).

Use these in your allocator.

One way to replace all uses of `std::container`s with ones that use your allocators is to write your own `notstd` namespace with template-aliases that replace the allocator (or whatever other retooling you want to do).  This custom allocator can then use your `TRACED_NEW_PLACEMENT` or `TRACED_NEW`.

And the result is a well defined program instead of a hack that, at best, currently works with your current compiler.